# JQuery Function code not running properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems with the code below. Basically it's 2 parts in the function...

Part 1 just clicks on a submit button and Part 2 shows a dialog.

For some reason both parts run separately work but when added together in the function no dialog appears, so when together Part 2 does not run.

Syntax issue?

Here's the code:

```
function myfunction() { 
    $('input[type=submit]#mysubmit').click();  

    $("#info").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    zIndex: 9999999,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});    
}
```

Update: I've tried commenting out Part 1 and the dialog still doesn't show up so it's something to do with the Dialog code ... Part 2

See below:

```
function myfunction() { 
    //$('input[type=submit]#mysubmit').click();   //commented out

    $("#info").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    zIndex: 9999999,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});    
}
```

Comment: Are you preventing the form from submitting (causing a page reload) when you click the submit button?

Comment: Please see update...It seems to be Part 2 .. The Dialog Part that has the problem

Comment: @Satch3000 See my attached answer / fiddle, the dialog appears: http://jsfiddle.net/TEN7Z/2/. Have you actually **included jquery-ui.js** and **jquery-ui.css**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try initializing and opening in 2 different places (right now, everytime you execute `myfunction`, the dialog gets initialized

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#info").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    zIndex: 9999999,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});    
});

function myfunction(){
    $("#info").dialog('open');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `autoOpen: false`. This option causes the dialog to be rendered invisible at initialisation.

Another option is to add `.dialog("open")` at the end:

```
$("#info").dialog(..autoOpen: false...).dialog('open');
```

Comparison (3x): http://jsfiddle.net/TEN7Z/2/